# NULL will convert into blank in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Facing issue while converting the Null for float Columns. I need a output where NULL will convert into blank and if it is not a NULL then it will the proper out with any precision value missing.

Example, I have below table “tbl_cost”:

```
PROD_ID  INT
IND_COST FLOAT(10,8)
PAK_COST FLOAT(10,8)
```

And I have written a View for the above table

```
Create View v_Cost
Begin 
    SELECT PROD_ID, IND_COST, PAK_COST
    FROM tbl_cost
End
```

Below is my query on view :

```
SELECT PROD_ID,
       CASE WHEN IND_COST IS NULL THEN '' ELSE  IND_COST END AS  IND_COST,
       CASE WHEN IND_COST IS NULL THEN '' ELSE  IND_COST END AS  IND_COST
FROM v_cost
```

I require a query on View only. Thanks in Advance for help.

Thanks,
Ajit

Comment: sample data can you provide ???

Comment: You can't change a float to an empty string. That is changing the datatype and you can't do that.

Comment: You could change the datatype to varchar and do this. ISNULL(cast(IND_COST as varchar(10)), '') as IND_COST.

Comment: Tried, but Rounding issue occured, We requires all decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope Change as per author request from @AjitKadam. 
**Decimal trailing zero removal**

```
Example:
1.00000  -> 1
32.50869 -> 32.50869
32.50870 -> 32.5087
1.00100  -> 1.001
```

**Script:**

```
DECLARE @tbl_cost TABLE (PROD_ID  INT,
                    IND_COST FLOAT(18),
                    PAK_COST FLOAT(18))
INSERT INTO  @tbl_cost
VALUES
(1, '32.5087', '2.00'),
(2, NULL, '32.50869'),
(3, '1.0010', NULL),
(4, NULL, NULL)

;WITH cte_Result AS
(
SELECT PROD_ID,
      ISNULL(LTRIM(Str(IND_COST, 25, 5)), '') AS IND_COST,
      ISNULL(LTRIM(Str(PAK_COST, 25, 5)), '') AS PAK_COST
FROM @tbl_cost
),cte_ResultFinal AS
(
select *
       ,CASE WHEN LEN(IND_COST)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(IND_COST,1,CHARINDEX('.',IND_COST)-1) ELSE '' END AS A_IND_COST
       ,CASE WHEN LEN(PAK_COST)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(PAK_COST,1,CHARINDEX('.',PAK_COST)-1) ELSE '' END AS A_PAK_COST
       ,REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(IND_COST,CHARINDEX('.',IND_COST)+1,LEN(IND_COST))) AS INT)) as B_IND_COST
       ,REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(PAK_COST,CHARINDEX('.',PAK_COST)+1,LEN(PAK_COST))) AS INT)) AS B_PAK_COST
from cte_Result
)
SELECT PROD_ID,
      A_IND_COST+CASE WHEN B_IND_COST ='0' THEN '' ELSE '.'+B_IND_COST END AS IND_COST,
      A_PAK_COST+CASE WHEN B_PAK_COST ='0' THEN '' ELSE '.'+B_PAK_COST END AS PAK_COST
FROM cte_ResultFinal
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
CREATE VIEW v_Cost
BEGIN
    SELECT PROD_ID,
          ISNULL(LTRIM(Str(IND_COST, 25, 5)), '') AS IND_COST,
          ISNULL(LTRIM(Str(PAK_COST, 25, 5)), '') AS PAK_COST
    FROM @tbl_cost
END
```

**Test:**

```
DECLARE @tbl_cost TABLE (PROD_ID  INT,
                    IND_COST FLOAT(18),
                    PAK_COST FLOAT(18))
INSERT INTO  @tbl_cost
VALUES
(1, '32.5087', '2.00'),
(2, NULL, '32.50869'),
(3, '1.0000', NULL),
(4, NULL, NULL)

SELECT PROD_ID,
      ISNULL(LTRIM(Str(IND_COST, 25, 5)), '') AS IND_COST,
      ISNULL(LTRIM(Str(PAK_COST, 25, 5)), '') AS PAK_COST
FROM @tbl_cost
```

Comment: Thanks but the decimal places are got rounded. example :Converted value(32.5087) and Original value (32.50869).

Comment: I added the values(32.5087) and (32.50869) in my example above and I do not see any rounding. Please can you verify.

Comment: @AjitKadam, Sorry I did not realize we were working with float. Please see my updated response.

Comment: ,It adding extra zeros after in decimal places for example if the IND_Cost is 1 and result it is adding extra five zeros (1,1.00000)

Comment: I have added another answer as the scope is different from the original question. Hope it helps. please see below for script.